# Transform an Excel matrix into values separated by commas

Tags: arrays, if-statement, array-formulas

I have a Matrix where column A has people name, then each column is has a date on the first line. For each line (person) ti can have the value 1 on the cell.

I would like to "reduce" this matrix to a single value per line (array), separated by commas.

Basically that's what I have:

```
Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | ... | 
Person   | 01/Jan   | 02/Jan   | 03/Jan   | ... |
John     | 1        |          |          | ... |
Paul     |          |          | 1        | ... |
Megan    | 1        |          | 1        | ... |
```

What I would like to have is (in another tab) a table like this:

```
Column A | Column B       | 
John     | 01/Jan         |
Paul     | 03/Jan         |
Megan    | 01/Jan, 03/Jan |
```

Comment: Please tag either Excel or Google-Sheets. Very different applications. If Excel, what version of Excel have you got, and do you have access to `TEXTJOIN()`.

Comment: @JvdV not tagging one specifically, because I'm willing to switch and use whatever allows me to achieve what I need. Sorry, I should have made it clear on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A2:A, 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:E=1, TO_TEXT(B1:E1)&",", )),,9^9))), ",$", )})
```

[image]